# Ng-file-upload show upload indicator

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm using ng-file-upload and want to show upload indicator during upload process, I haven't found the way to do this in documentation, but may be there is a way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even I was looking for a directive and tried using this one but then I moved to a better one that worked for me and was easy to configur and use and documentation and demos are enough to get the things right

Look at this directive:
https://github.com/nervgh/angular-file-upload

Answer (score 0):

The third argument of the then method has the progress.

```
Upload.upload({
        url: 'upload/url',
    }).then(function (resp) {
        ....
    }, function (resp) {
        ....
    }, function (evt) {
        var progressPercentage = parseInt(100.0 * evt.loaded / evt.total);
        console.log('progress: ' + progressPercentage + '% ' + evt.config.data.file.name);
    });
```